# Which data structure to represent Sudoku puzzle, and solve it by finding naked single / hidden single

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, sudoku

I'm hesitate about which of following two data structure should be use to represent a sudoku board, in order to solve it by using **naked single** and **hidden single** technique.

1.

```
//using bool array to store candidates of a cell.
int[,] board = new int[9,9];
bool[,] isFixed = new bool[9,9]; // determine cell is fixed.
bool[,,] candidates = new bool[9,9,9];
```

in this way, we can check if a cell (row,col) contains a candidate n by checking wheather `candidates[row, col, n]` is true or false

2.

```
int[,] board = new int[9,9];
bool[,] isFixed = new bool[9,9]; // determine cell is fixed.
bool[,] row = new bool[9,9]; //row(1,2) = true means number 2 was already appear (is solved or fixed) in 1st row
bool[,] col = new bool[9,9]; //col(1,2) = true means number 2 was already appear (is solved or fixed) in 1st col
bool[,] square3x3 = new bool[9,9]; //square3x3 (1,2) = true means number 2 was already appear (is solved or fixed) in 1st square3x3
```

in this way, we can check if a cell (r,c) contains a candidate n by checking wheather expression `row[r, n] && col[c, n] && square3x3[r/3 * 3 + c/3, n]` is true or false

when a certain cell is solved with number n, in 1st way, we must update the candidates of all 3x9 cell in row, col, square3x3 of a certain cell, while in 2nd way, we just only set row[,n] , col[,n] and square3x3[,n] to true.

But I'm not sure which way is suitably and efficient to find naked single and hidden single.

Can anybody suggest me a algorithm to find hidden single?

Help me, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to find hidden singles etc? You can solve a sudoku pretty quickly without all those fancy things, with just a naive depth first search that prunes branches that are definitely impossible.

Comment: @harold I do not need to solve it quickly, but logically. I want to build a sudoku app to help human solve it step by step. So other method such as backtracking... should be give away.

Comment: Oh ok, well that's hard, last time I read a real paper about sudoku's it was still unknown (ie unproven) whether it is in general possible to solve all sudoku's logically, though many (most?) believe it is.

Comment: I know that a hard sudoku puzzle can not be solved with only logical techniques; but you know, after applying logical techniques first, we can reduce a lot of candidates to before using trial and error technique

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use a set of basic arrays that you would have to keep in sync, but a Board class.

This would have internally a 9x9 array of Field items, which would hold an optional (`int?`) given number, an optional derived number and a list (`bool[9]`) of candidates.

This class would expose some properties/methods to get at a specific cell or row/column/block.

Answer (score -1):

When I was solving sudoku myself, I got away with just two multi-dimensional arrays.

One was containing current state of the field (cells are numbers) and the other - probable next state of field (cells are arrays of numbers).

You can probably get some ideas from my code (it's in Ruby, though)

https://github.com/stulentsev/sudoku-solver/blob/master/solver.rb

Comment: Take it or leave it, guys. :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar to ruby, can you explain which algorithm you use in your code?

Comment: Just something I came up with. I was solving Sudoku on my ipad and I grew tired of calculating options. So I figured a couple of heuristics I used as a human and coded them. As a result, this script was able to solve every sudoku I could get my hands on. Acceptable job, I guess :-)